# How to enable Change Tracking in Word 2016 document where parts of the document is locked for editing

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a word document with multiple pages. The first page contains few content controls, but that page is locked (using password protection), so no changes could be made on page 1. The content controls are populated with data using OpenXML SDK and some C# code

This document is being used by our users, and they open it in Microsoft Word (office 365 desktop edition). They want to enable "Track Changes" and "Comments" feature while editing the document, but those controls on the ribbon are all grayed out in Microsoft Word.

[image]

Is there a way to have protected content in a word document and also enable Change Tracking?. If not, what is the reason? Any help in resolving this issue is truly appreciated.

Comment: When locking, presumably via the Restrict Editing icon on the Review tab, have you allowed "Tracked changes" under "Allow only this type of editing in the document"?

Comment: That option allows "Only Tracked Changes".  So all edits are tracked now. That takes away the ability for the user to decide if tracking should be enabled or not.

Comment: I don't think that Microsoft developers have foreseen your needs. You might need to do the locking yourself using VBA and leave the users free to track changes or not.